# How to instrument a spring boot application using java agent and javassist?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, javassist, javaagents

1. I have a spring boot project. I want to instrument this application using java agent and javassist library. I have created a maven project for java agent with Premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) method and build a jar file for maven project.
2. Now I am running using java agent command
   -> java -javaagent:"maven project jar file" -jar "spring boot project jar file"
3. I want to know above approach is correct or not.
4. If it is correct how to retrieve invoked method class name using javassist.

This is **Java agent** class

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) throws InstantiationException {

        log.info("....Starting Java Agent......");
        System.out.println("Java agent Premain Method");
        InterceptingClassTransformer interceptingClassTransformer = new InterceptingClassTransformer();
        interceptingClassTransformer.init();
        instrumentation.addTransformer(interceptingClassTransformer);
        
        
    }
```

This is **InterceptingClassTransformer** class

```
@Override
    public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
            ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

        byte[] byteCode = classfileBuffer;
        HashMap<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("className", className);
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue().contains("com/example/ebanking/controller")) {
                log.info("Transforming the class " + className);
                try {
                    ClassPool classPool = scopedClassPoolFactory.create(loader, rootPool,
                            ScopedClassPoolRepositoryImpl.getInstance());
                    CtClass ctClass = classPool.makeClass(new ByteArrayInputStream(classfileBuffer));
                    CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();                   
                    for (CtMethod method : methods) {                       
                            final StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();                         
                            String name = method.getName();
                            buffer.append("System.err.println(\"Method Name: "+ name + " executed\" );");
                            method.insertBefore(buffer.toString());
                            method.addLocalVariable("startTime", CtClass.longType);
                            method.insertBefore("startTime = System.nanoTime();");
                            method.insertAfter("System.out.println(\"Execution Duration "
                                    + "(nano sec): \"+ (System.nanoTime() - startTime) );");
                            //method.insertBefore("System.out.println(\"Logging using Agent Before \");");
                            method.insertAfter("System.out.println(\"Logging using After Method execution\");");
                        }

                    

                    byteCode = ctClass.toBytecode();
                    ctClass.detach();
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error in transforming the class: " + className, ex);
                }
            }
            
        }
        return byteCode;
    }
```

--> **com/example/ebanking/controller** this package is in spring boot project.

Comment: Does this work as you expect?

Comment: Yes, I am able to get invoked method name.